# Pseudo class :empty and :not(:empty) - make it hide() and show() regarding content (jquery, mvc 5, asp.net, css)

Tags: jquery, css, hide, asp.net-mvc-5, show

I am having  a problem with :empty and :not(:empty)(jquery, mvc 5, asp.net, css). 
My aim is to make the error message visible only if there is a text like "The Street field is required." and otherwise make it disappear.
It works only partly.

On the server side it looks like:

```
<div class="BWForm_form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4 BWTextLeft">
        @Html.BWLabelFor(model => model.street, new { @class = "BWLabel" })
        <b>/</b>
        @Html.BWLabelFor(model => model.streetNo, new { @class = "BWLabel" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-9 BWPaddingRight">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.street, new { @class = "BWForm_form-control BWTextBox" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 BWPaddingLeft">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.streetNo, new { @class = "BWForm_form-control BWTextBox" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.street)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.streetNo)

    </div>
</div>
```

The relevant part for my problem is only "@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.street)", which will cause the original HTML to look like(only the relevant code):

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="receiverAddress.street"></span>
```

If an error occured(when sending the form, and detecting errors) the following HTML will be shown (the previous("original HTML") html will completely replaced):

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="receiverAddress.street">
<span class="" for="receiverAddress_street">The Street field is required.</span>
</span
```

My idea was to do it like(it works):

```
 $('span.field-validation-error:empty').hide();
 $('span.field-validation-valid:empty').hide();
```

But than I want to re-display it like again(this doesn't work) :

```
$('span.field-validation-error:not(:empty)').show(100);
$('span.field-validation-valid:not(:empty)').show(100);
```

The Html looks still like(style="display: none;" it is still disabled):

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="receiverAddress.street" style="display: none;">

    <span class="" for="receiverAddress_street">

        The Street field is required.

    </span>

</span>
```

But what can I do to display it back again and why doesn't it work ?

Ty for helping.
Martin

(updated: added additional informations)

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (pattern)

updated

```
$(function () {
  $("span[class^=field-validation]")
  .each(function (i, el) {
    if ( $(el).text().length > 1 ) {
      $(el).css("display", "block")
    };
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/tF2YJ/